# Why is $\sum\limits_{k\ge0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}t^{2k+1}A^{2k+1}$ absolut convergent?

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

> Why is $\sin(tA)=\sum\limits_{k\ge0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}t^{2k+1}A^{2k+1}$ absolute convergent ? for a $n\times n$ real matrix $A$ and $t\in \mathbf R$

Which crieterion is to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that the power series
$$
\sin(x)=\sum\limits_{k\ge0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}
$$ has an *infinite radius of convergence* and use the fact that
$$
\left|\left|\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}t^{2k+1}A^{2k+1}\right|\right| \leq \frac{1}{(2k+1)!}|t|^{2k+1}\left|\left|A\right|\right|^{2k+1}.
$$

Comment: @Oliver Oloa So $t||A||$ is a number and $\sin(t||A||)\ge\sin(tA)$ and you show that the former is absolute convergent, or is it ''clear'' from the definition that it should be

Comment: $\sin(tA)$ is defined as a series, this makes sense if the series is convergent, that is if $||\sin(tA)||<\infty$.