# $t\mapsto\sin(tA)$ is continuous

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, continuity, matrix-calculus

> How to show that $t\mapsto\sin(tA)$ is continuous for  a real matrix $A\in Mat(n,n)$

Can I use trigonometric identity,

$\sin y-\sin x=2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\sin(y-x)$ but this holds only for real numbers, does it matter ?

Comment: I don't know for sure if it holds for matrices as well. One potential problem is the commutativity. But even if it does, it isn't of much help for your problem I think.

Comment: @Vim thanks for your answer but why not, commutatitivity is not an issue I think, because you have here only $1$ matrix. so if $y$ approaches $x$ then on the RHS $||\sin((y-x)A)||\le|\sin(|y-x|||A||)|\to 0$

Comment: why $\sin (tA)\le |\sin (|t|\|A\|)$?

Comment: @Vim $|\sin(tA)|\le|\sin(|r|\lvert\lvert A\rvert\rvert)|$ by triangle inequality

Comment: can you elaborate? I don't think triangle inequality would apply in apparent ways, since $\sin(\cdot)$ involves both $e^{\pm i(\cdot)}$.

Comment: @Vim I mean the series expansion of it http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1795308/337759

Comment: As you can see, $\sin $ involved both positive and negative terms, but if you use the triangle inequality, it would eliminate all the negative signs and couldn't lead to a new sine series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, $\sin tA=\frac1{2i}(e^{itA}-e^{-itA})$. So you need only to show that 
$$t\mapsto e^{itA},\quad t\in\Bbb R$$
is continuous. (For the $e^{-itA}$ part, just note that it is the inverse of $e^{itA}$ and that taking inverse is a continuous map in the invertible matrix space. [Or rather, we don't even need to bother with taking inverse, thanks to @Dr.MV's comment, we only need to note that it's a composition of $t\mapsto -t\mapsto e^{-itA}$]).

Now, for $x,y\in\Bbb R$, we see that 
$$\|e^{ixA}-e^{iyA}\|\le\|e^{ixA}\|\|I-e^{i(y-x)A}\|\le\|e^{ixA}\| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n!}(|y-x|\|A\|)^n.$$
So it reduces to show the following limit
$$\lim_{s\to 0^+}(e^{s}-1)=0. $$

Comment: Clear and concise.  +1

Comment: @Dr.MV thanks. Although I think if everything's to be spelled out, like the continuity of taking inverse, or the famous $\|AB\|\le \|A\|\|B\|$ etc., it could still be quite long.

Comment: One need not use the fact that $e^{-itA}=(e^{itA})^{-1}$.  Instead just note the parameter inversion $t\to -t$

Comment: @Dr.MV oh you really beat me here!